# Python/Tipfy/Jinja2: ImportError: No module named ext.jinja2

Tags: python, google-app-engine, tipfy

Aloha,

having some spare time and trying out python on app engine as it is much more flexible than java, I wanted to use Tipfy as my webapp framework.

My problem ist, that, whenever I try to import something like jinja2, I get:

```
from tipfy.ext.jinja2 import render_response
ImportError: No module named ext.jinja2
```

I ensured that under lib/dist there is the jinja2 folder.

Other stuff like Session doesn't work either :(

Any help to a noob? Their IRC chat wasn't a help and the documentation didn't mention any such problems.

Thank you :)

Comment: Why are you importing the same component twice?

Comment: Sorry, misstyped. I'll correct it asap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the newest tipfy version (1.0b1), the jinja2 extension is now bundled with tipfy.

```
from tipfyext import jinja2
```

Are you using that version? I'm sorry because the documentation is outdated and 
doesn't reflect this.

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked as expected now :-) Could have seen this in the demo app skeleton as well, was a bit blind there. Just one short question: Have you got any idea why I can't have my handerls in a subfolder called 'handler'? It always tells me that the handler could not be found :-/ Everything is quite strange to me as of now...

Comment: Did you add a `__init__.py` to the subfolder?

Comment: Yes I did. I had a typo error... pretty weird switching from Java to Python but I am getting more and more used to it :) Start liking it a bit :)